# Adding multiple marker locations in Google Maps Android API V2

Tags: android, api, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using Google Map API v2 in my application to show Maps.
i want to add multiple location  (LatLng)

```
main.java


GoogleMap mMap;
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    final LatLng CIU = new LatLng(35.21843892856462, 33.41662287712097);
    Marker ciu = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                              .position(CIU).title("My Office"));


}
```

}

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming *questions*. What is your *question*?

Comment: how can i marker multiple location  in google maps v2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your code, you need firstly `set up the map`:

```
// Initial Map
        try {

            if (googleMap == null) {
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and call the `addMarker()`:

```
LatLng CIU = new LatLng(35.21843892856462, 33.41662287712097);
    Marker ciu = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                              .position(CIU).title("My Office"));
```

For Adding multiple markers, call `addMarker()` again:

```
addressMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(addressPos).title("Address"));
```

Please download the example code on my github [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/GoogleMapExample-android).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> how can i marker multiple location in google maps v2

You are welcome to call `addMarker()` multiple times to add multiple markers at various locations. You already have code that calls it once -- just call it as many times as is needed.